# C# design issue: two immutable objects with references to each other

Tags: c#, oop

I'm writing a fairly large application in C#/WPF. I use the Builder pattern to create objects which are always in a consistent state, and the objects are immutable.

I've come across a problem in this design which I don't know how to fix.

Consider the following two classes:

```
public class Employee {
    public string Name { get; }
    public double Salary { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<EmployeeBonus> Bonuses { get; } // read-only list of bonuses

    public Employee(string name, double salary, IEnumerable<EmployeeBonus> bonuses) {
        Name = name;
        Salary = salary;
        Bonuses = new List<EmployeeBonus>(bonuses); // list of bonuses initialized in constructor
    }
}

public class EmployeeBonus {
    public Employee Employee { get; } // bonus has reference to Employee
    public string Description { get; }
    public double Amount { get; }

    public EmployeeBonus(Employee employee, string description, double amount) {
        Employee = employee; // employee must be initialized in constructor
        Description = description;
        Amount = amount;
    }
}
```

So - I have an Employee class which includes a list of Bonuses each employee receives. The EmployeeBonus class includes a reference back to the Employee.
Since both classes are immutable, each one must be initialized with a reference to the other. But this is, of course, impossible, because I can't create an object with a reference to another object which doesn't exist.

Solutions I thought about:

A. I thought about not having a reference to Employee in EmployeeBonus, so EmployeeBonus only needs Description and Amount to be constructed. But this breaks my Repository pattern: my `Repository<EmployeeBonus>` has an Add method which takes in ONLY an EmployeeBonus. In order to save this object correctly, I need to know which employee owns it, and because the method only takes in an EmployeeBonus - this object must contain the Employee.

B. I thought about adding an AddBonus(string description, double amount) method to Employee, so that the list of bonuses is not initialized in the constructor, but instead each bonus is added later and the Employee class attaches itself to each bonus - but that will make the Employee no longer immutable.

C. I could break my generic Repository and create another method, `Add(EmployeBonus bonus, Employee employee)`, and then remove Employee from EmployeeBonus - but then my EmployeeBonusRepository won't inherit from `Repository<EmployeeBonus>`.

D. The most correct solution I could think of (correct but very wasteful) is this:

```
public class Employee 
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public double Salary { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<EmployeeBonus> Bonuses { get; }

    public Employee(string name, double salary, IEnumerable<EmployeeBonus> bonuses) {
        Name = name;
        Salary = salary;
        Bonuses = new List<EmployeeBonus>(bonuses);
    }
}

public class EmployeeBonus 
{
    public string Description { get; }
    public double Amount { get; }

    public EmployeeBonus(string description, double amount) {
        Description = description;
        Amount = amount;
    }
}

public class EmployeeBonusWithEmployee 
{
    public Employee Employee { get; }
    public EmployeeBonus Bonus { get; }

    public EmployeeBonusWithEmployee(Employee employee, EmployeeBonus bonus) 
    {
        Employee = employee;
        Bonus = bonus;
    }
}

public class EmployeeBonusWithEmployeeRepository : Repository<EmployeeBonusWithEmployee>
{
    public void Add(EmployeeBonusWithEmployee bonus)
    {
        // save complete employee bonus
    }
}

public class EmployeeRepository : Repository<Employee>
{
    //...
    public void Add(Employee employee)
    {
        // saves employee first, 
        // then creates an EmployeeBonusWithEmployee object for each EmployeeBonus in the list
        // and saves it using an EmployeeBonusWithEmployeeRepository
    }
}
```

Does this solution (D) make sense? Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: First question that comes to mind. What is the reason for using `IReadOnlyList`? And what is the reason behind everything being "Immutable"?

Comment: I want to keep the power to create objects and deal with object logic only in the hands of Builder classes. Once a builder creates an object, it cannot be modified, unless it is by using another builder.

Comment: Maybe you could pass a reference to a list to Employee's constructor and return a readonly wrapper in the getter. That allows only whoever constructed the Employee to modify the list. I'm not sure I'd call this solution elegant though...

Comment: You can add constructor to Employee which does not accept bonuses and add WithBonuses method which returns _new_ Employee with bonuses set. That way things are still immutable, and employee without bonuses is still consistent state (unlike bonus without Employee).

Comment: It's impossible to have two truly immutable objects that reference each other in C#, because the reality is that one has to be created before the other exists, and thus changed (mutated) afterwards.  You can have "sort-of" immutable, or mutate-once objects.

Comment: You can still return something that is immutable to the "end-user", which might be enough. That said, I think I'd still prefer to make the list mutable or try to remove the Employee reference from the Bonus somehow. I'd rather give up that ultimate guarantee and get code that is much easier to understand.

Comment: **Do not use doubles to represent money**.  Use `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

To create mutually referencing objects in C#, you need to delay the mutually referencing code from executing - until both objects have been created.

```
 public class B
 {
     private Lazy<A> _a;

     public A GetA 
     { 
         get { return _a.Value; } 
     }

     public B(Lazy<A> forLater)
     {
         _a = forLater;
     }
 }
```

And the same with class A.
Then to create the mutually referencing objects:

```
 A a = null;
 B b = null;

 a = new A(new Lazy<B>(() => b));
 b = new B(new Lazy<A>(() => a));
```

[Lazy<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) delays execution of code until later, allowing both constructors to complete.

This is a terrible solution - other languages make this easier - so i would suggest a more practical approach.

- make them mutable, or
- take Employee out of EmployeeBonus

Comment: That's not really immutable though.. since they mutate on the first access.  Perhaps you could call them mutate-once objects.

Answer (score 1):

Solution one:

Give each employee a unique key; let's suppose it is a guid for the sake of argument.

Create an immutable global lookup:

```
static ImmutableDictionary<Guid, Employee> employees = ... ;
```

And then when you create a new employee:

```
Guid key = Guid.NewGuid(); // NOT new Guid() !
EmployeeBonus[] bs = new [] { new EmployeeBonus(key, description, amount) };
Employee e = new Employee(key, name, salary, bs);
employees = employees.Add(key, e);
```

Now you're set.  Everything is immutable except for variable "employees", and to go from a bonus to an employee just requires you to get the key from the bonus and look it up in the dictionary.

---

Solution two:

Create an immutable directed labelled graph type.  Developing an immutable directed labelled graph is left as an exercise. It's fun!

```
static Graph g = Graph.Empty;
```

When you create a new employee, add a node to the graph.  Graphs are immutable, so this produces a new graph.

```
Employee e = new Employee(name, salary);
Bonus b = new Bonus(amount);
g = g.AddNode(e);
g = g.AddNode(b);
g = g.AddEdge(e, b, "Bonus");
g = g.AddEdge(b, e, "Employee");
```

So now you have an employee, you want to know what bonuses they have, you consult the graph:

```
// What nodes of the graph are connected to e by an edge "Bonus"?
IEnumerable<Bonuses> bs = g.GetNeighbors(e, "Bonus").OfType<Bonus>();
```

If you have a bonus and you want the employee, same thing.

```
Employee e = g.GetNeighbors(b, "Employee").OfType<Employee>().Single();
```

---

Solution three:

Instead of a graph, maintain an immutable ledger of actions taken.  A ledger is a list of transactions that can only be extended from the end, never edited in the middle.  Developing such a type is left as an exercise.

```
static Ledger ledger = Ledger.Empty;

...

Employee e = new Employee(name, salary);
Bonus b = new Bonus(amount);
ledger = ledger.AddHire(e);
ledger = ledger.AddBonus(e, b);
...
```

Now when you want to know what bonuses are associated with an employee, or what employees are associated with a bonus you *filter the ledger to get a sequence of matching add bonus events*.

---

Notice that all of these solutions are basically the same. Every object is immutable, but there is always a mutable variable that contains a source of global truth, and that variable changes as the world changes.

Each one of these solutions has different performance characteristics, so think about what operations you are likely to perform.   Note also that the dictionary and graph solutions lose information about what order events happened in; it might be important to you to be able to run queries that involve the sequence of events in time.

Also note that these solutions all have different garbage collection performance characteristics. The dictionary and ledger solutions keep the employees alive forever.